# RWD Theme in version 2.0

Tags: rwd-theme, rwd, magento2

Can anyone confirm? I heard that the RWD theme will no longer be an available option during install when Community version 2.0 is released. A rumor or fact?

Answer (score 7):

Long answer short,

Magento 2.0 is a complete overhaul from Magento 1.0. There will be a new base RWD theme in Magento 2.0.

Does it look the same as Magento 1.0 RWD theme? No

That being said, it is still in beta, so it could change.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, In Magento 2 stable version RWD has been removed and it included following two in-built themes.

1. Blank (Magento Blank)
2. Luma (Magento Luma)

These both are responsive.